# Very weird behavior of $.mobile.changePage in a very simple jQuery Mobile page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm writing a Html 5 application for mobile devices using jQuery mobile (and Phonegap, but the following is device independent), using one html page that contains various <div data-role="page"... > elements as subpages. To change between one subpage and another I use $.mobile.changePage. **Everything works well *unless* I place a div tag into one of the <div data-role="content"> containers!**

Working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.mobile.changePage($('#page2'), {
                transition : 'slideup',
                reverse : false,
                changeHash : true
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="content">
            Page1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="content">
            Page2
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, after adding something as simple as a closed div tag behind Page1

```
Page1 -> Page1<div />
```

$.mobile.changePage still fires - one can see the page2 content for a second - but then shows a blank screen.

This happens in desktop browsers as well as in a smartphone (using Phonegap and adjusting the code).

I really appreciate any kind of idea or hint. Narrowing down this problem and making it reproducible alone cost me hours a valuable livetime because it seemed to unlikely....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
Page1<div />
```

to

```
Page1</div>
```

...

```
Page1<div>test</div>
```

works too.

Not sure why jqm is having a problem with the trailing / on the empty div.

Comment: You are right, this works. I used the empty div with an id in order to add html content, but didn't play around enough. Probably simply a jqm bug. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe the div is a self closing element so syntax wise this would be incorrect <div />